# Drupal 9. Modo debug para plantillas twig se me ha quitado de ayer para hoy

Tags: drupal, drupal9

tenia el modo debug activado y de un dia para otro se me ha quitado, a que puede ser debido ? A temas de limpieza de cache o algo ??

Ya no veo los comentarios que me sugieren los nombres de las plantillas.

Comment: Te dejé una referencia muy útil en el chat

Answer (score 1):

Por desgracia no puedo comentar todavía, así que te doy una posible solución a esto vía respuesta.

En Drupal ^8.8 y ^9, si haces la instalación vía composer y luego instalas otro módulo por este método, o hacer un composer update, por alguna razón, se sobreescribe este fichero y se pierde la configuración.

En mi caso lo he solucionado indicándole a Drupal en el settings.local.php que use otro fichero de la siguiente forma:

```
$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/devel.services.yml';
```

En este nuevo fichero coloco la configuración que se espera esté situada en developmen.services.yml.
Ahora, al realizar cualquier operación con composer ya no se me sobreescribe este fichero.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo tendre en cuenta a partir de ahora :)

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado el porque.

Por algún motivo se me ha reseteado el fichero de configuracion que se encarga de decir si activar o no este modo ( **development.services.yml** ), dentro de `web/sites` .

Lo he vuelto a poner de la siguiente manera para que me **muestre los comentarios del debugging** .

```
# Local development services.
#
# To activate this feature, follow the instructions at the top of the
# 'example.settings.local.php' file, which sits next to this file.

    parameters:
      http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
      twig.config:
        debug : true
        auto_reload: true
        cache: false
    services:
      cache.backend.null:
        class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

Y por defecto ( *de esta manera no muestra los comentarios* ) venia asi:

```
# Local development services.
#
# To activate this feature, follow the instructions at the top of the
# 'example.settings.local.php' file, which sits next to this file.
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

Espero echar una mano a quien le pase esto de **que se le borre 'de repente' el debug**

Lo unico que desconozco es que no se que he podido tocar para que se resetee, si alguien sabe una posible accion que cause esto, porfavor, que lo deje en comentarios de esta respuesta.

---

#### Ojo!

Esto funcionara si configurastes previamente tu subtheme personalizado. Ya que en mi caso solo se perdio la **referencia**